# Git workflow, am I doing it right?

Tags: php, git, installation, workflow

More and more projects are starting to pile up and I want some workflow and also version control over the different projects. I'm trying to set the "right" workflow with Xampp, Git, GitDesktop and PhpStorm on a Windows 2012r2 machine.

- Xampp base: `d:\xampp`
- `http://localhost` = `d:\xampp\htdocs`
- Dev repositories: `d:\xampp\htdocs\repositories\dev\GitDemo`
- Live repositories: `d:\xampp\htdocs\repositories\live\GitDemo`
- Live folder: `d:\xampp\htdocs\GitDemo`
- Live URL: `http://servername/GitDemo` (intranet use only)

Right now I have my repositories folder inside the htdocs folder, otherwise I would need another alias/copy action to be able to see what I'm developing. But at the same time the `repositories` folder is exposed. How to hide this? htaccess?

I've ran `git init --bare` inside the live folder for this project. With GitDesktop I've created the repository for `GitDemo` inside `d:\xampp\htdocs\repositories\dev`.

Using PhpStorm I've created a project based upon local files and pointed it towards `d:\xampp\htdocs\repositories\dev\GitDemo`. I'm able to see the changes made using `git status`, add them using `git add .` and commit them succesfully with `git commit -m "my commit.."`.

I've created a remote server `git remote add live master` and created a `post-receive` to checkout the files inside `d:\xampp\htdocs\repositories\live\GitDemo` to `d:\xampp\htdocs\GitDemo`.

This all feels like a "ton" of work to set up initially and somewhat redundant (having the same files in 3 locations).

Is this the ideal way to set this up, or do you suggest an alternative approach? Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: *"checkout the files inside `d:/xampp/htdocs/repositories/live/GitDemo` to `d:/xampp/htdocs/GitDemo`"* seems redundant. Why don't you just use the latter location as the production repository? The rest of your setup seems reasonable.

Comment: Yeah I came to the same conclusion, I've used a symlink and also put the repositories outside the htdocs folder (see my answer). Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about the most logical solution (to my opinion at this moment). Here's how I solved my unclear items as described:

I've optimized it by:

- Bringing the repositories directory outside htdocs to `d:\repositories\dev\` and `d:\repositories\live`.
- I've set up a symlink to `http://localhost/dev/GitDemo` that links to
  `d:\repositories\dev\GitDemo`. In this way I don't need to place the
  repositories folder inside the htdocs folder and still benefit from
  Apache being able to serve the content, which actually resides outside the htdocs folder.
- The live version is now placed at `http://localhost/GitDemo` and with a post-receive hook it gets deployed from `d:\repositories\live\GitDemo.git` to `d:\xampp\htdocs\GitDemo`.

If you think I made a mistake or have mistaken something from the way it's supposed to be, please correct me as I'm still not sure this is the correct way but at least it seems like it to me.